# Why enzyme `mount` can't find text in inner components?

Tags: reactjs, chai, enzyme

I defined some react components:

**src/hello.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Box from './box.jsx';

class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {fruit} = this.props;
    return <div>
      <h1>Hello, I like:</h1>
      {
        fruit.map((name, index) => <Box name={name} key={index}/>)
      }
    </div>
  }
}

export default Hello;
```

**src/box.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Box extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {name} = this.props;
    return <div>Box: {name}</div>
  }
}
```

And use `enzyme` to test it:

**spec/hello-spec.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Hello from '../src/hello.jsx';
import chai from 'chai';
import spies  from 'chai-spies';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import jsdomGlobal from 'jsdom-global';

jsdomGlobal();

chai.should();

describe('<Hello />', () => {

  it('shows names in inner components', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Hello fruit={['AAA', 'BBB']}/>);
    // AAA will be rendered by inner components
    wrapper.contains("AAA").should.be.true;
  });

});
```

Run test:

```
mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive spec
```

But the test is always fail.

If I verify a text in the `Hello` component it self, like:

```
wrapper.contains("Hello, I like:").should.be.true;
```

It will pass.

Is it expected behavior? How can I test text of inner components?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with `wrapper.text().to.have.string('AAA');` instead ?

Comment: This is one possible way